# Cannot access any library in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

Currently I am working on a project and I need to access various different libraries, but the problem is that I am very stuck. My program is a web based application which uses ethereum blockchain (ganache, truffle, metamask). I am trying for example to access the library web3-eth-accounts through a JavaScript file which I access with the press of a button in my website, but all that happens is this:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'web3-eth-accounts'
    at o (web3.min.js:1)
    at o (web3.min.js:1)
    at Object.init (Test.js:4)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (statePrototype.html:26)
```

JavaScript:

```js
Test = {

    init : function () {
        var Web3EthAccounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');

        var account = new Web3EthAccounts('ws://localhost:7545');

    }
}
```

All of the libraries including web3-eth-accounts are in the node-modules folder.

[Here is an image of all of the files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBuI7.jpg)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Certificate System</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- Pagrindinis htmlo kodas -->
<h1>Student State Prototype</h1>

<button onclick="App.render()">Show Student State</button>

<p id = "StatePrint"></p>

<button onclick="App.fail()">Make Student Fail</button>

<button onclick="App.complete()">Make Student Complete the Course</button>

<button onclick="Test.init()">Test</button>

<hr />

<form action="index.html">
    <button class="pageSwitch" type="submit">Back to HOMEPAGE</button>
</form>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/web3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/truffle-contract.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src = "js/Test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any reason for having the `<script .../>` at the bottom. have you tried to move the script tag to the top. it looks like you are trying to access "Test" before it is loaded onto the browser.

Comment: There are other imports bellow so I just added it near them I will make an edit on how it looks overall.

Answer (score 0):

All you did was instantiate it, you never created an account.  You have to call

```
account.create();
```

from the docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3-eth-accounts

Comment: Sorry, I had made a mistake writing the error message, yes the problem is not in the code (even though I know its not instantiated), but that the module web3-eth-accounts is not found